# How to reduce the blank center space between float:left & float:right in CSS?

Tags: magento-1.9, css

Current Output

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="price-box">
    <p class="special-price" style="float: left;">
            <span class="price" id="product-price-475">£349.99</span>
    </p>
    <p class="old-price" style="float: left;">
            <span class="price" id="old-price-475">£399.99</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Now I need to reduce center blank space as follows

[image]

Comment: Maybe have the problem with your class file, I just checked in [pen](https://codepen.io) it's working. Please provide in details(CSS or Url)

Comment: https://goo.gl/UNhPOg this is the page

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to say without viewing all your code, if you can't track down what's causing the gap (is there any padding/margin?) then you could just move the 'was' price to the left with some CSS like this:

```
margin-left: -10px;
```

Or

```
position: relative;
right: 10px;
```

Also, I would avoid writing inline styles. It's pretty poor practice and can make maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: https://goo.gl/UNhPOg this is page. Yeah, I wont use inline styles. I did it just explain here.

Comment: we cannot use margin-left, when the special price goes 4 or 5 digit then the old price will be above the special price

Comment: Have you updated the site? As I can't replicate it in Chrome on OSx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output!!

```
.product-view .product-shop .white-back .price-box .special-price .price {
font-size: 45px;
float: left;
position: relative;
right: 10%;

.product-view .product-shop .white-back .price-box .old-price .price {
float: left;
margin-top: 18px;
color: #c2812f;
position: relative;
left: 40%;
```

Comment: It will add blank space in the middle when you close the inspect element